# How to make a simple football standing table layout

Tags: android

I am trying to make a custom league standing as this one :
[image]

I really have no knowledge how to start. I have searched here but no clear idea or tutorial how to start.

Honestly i didn t try anything because i can t find similar ideas.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: that looks like an ExpandableListView for me. Each row is a List item.

Comment: yes you can use ExpandableListView for achieve this

Comment: check this Link : https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/

Comment: How can i make the rank ID,Team,Points headers ?
and the rows as : 1 Germany 0 0 ...

 Is there any tutorials or ideas using expandable listview

Comment: Check the links above and look for custom adapter with ExpandableListView

Comment: Thanks all i got the idea about ExpandableListView i think that s what i am  searching for